# Is jQuery's $ safe from XSS?

Tags: jquery, xss

In jQuery:

```
$('<script>alert("foo");</script>')
// nothing shows up 

// wrap it in a <p> 
$('<script>alert("foo");</script>').wrap('<p>')
// oh no, an alert just popped up.
```

Is `$('any string what so ever')` able to cause JavaScript to execute on any browser?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### No $ is not XSS safe.

You can inject arbitrary JavaScript using this trick.

```
$("<img src=x onerror=alert(/xss/.source)>")
```

Comment: fyi, if you are looking for safety: Google Cajole has a pretty robust one: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/commit/0c085059c9d16766d3680992a6ec5cfef0797bea ... other option is the more modern, https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser